# Django jquery-ui Autocomplete with database

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to use jquery-ui autocomplete plugin with my model.
I have this model:

```
class Baslik(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

To make this done I used the codes below:
input:

```
<input id="n" type="text" name="n"/>
```

js:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $( "input#n" ).autocomplete({
                            source: "{% url "autoco" %}",
                            minLength: 2
        });
});
</script>
```

view:

```
def autoco(request):
     term = request.GET.get('term')
     bslk = Baslik.objects.filter(title__istartswith=term)
     res = []
     for b in bslk:
          dict = {'id':b.id, 'label':b.__unicode__(), 'value':b.__unicode__()}
          res.append(dict)
     return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(res))
```

url:

```
url(r'^autoco/$', 'autoco', name='autoco'),
```

but it still does not work. When I just use local values in js code it works fine but in this case I cannot get any auto complete. When I type something to input, terminal shows a log like `"GET /autoco/?term=se HTTP/1.1" 500 9892` What I did wrong. Any opinion would help. Thanks.

Comment: Please look at the Network tab in your browser's dev tools and show the traceback for the Ajax request. Or, go to "/autoco/?term=se" directly in the browser to see the traceback there.

Comment: When I go to "/autoco/?term=se"  it says `TypeError at /autoco/
'str' object is not callable`

Comment: And what is the *rest* of the traceback?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8171014/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your urls.py. You can't refer to the view just as the string `'autoco'`. Either refer to it as `'myapp.views.autoco'`, or import the actual view function and refer to it directly as `autoco` without the quotes.

Comment: Now it says `NameError at /autoco/
global name 'simplejson' is not defined` Is there any chance to u know cause of this too?

Comment: Have you imported simplejson inside your views.py?

Comment: I used `import json`. I guess it's not the required import. I tried `import django.utils.simplejson`. It didn't work. Edit: I used `from django.utils import simplejson` and it worked. Thanks a lot.