# Django jquery-ui Autocomplete with database 2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, jquery-ui

I'm sorry to dig up a subject (this one : [Django jquery-ui Autocomplete with database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552301/django-jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-database)) but it's old so there are maybe some modifications since this one.

I want to do the exact same thing than malisit, I tried the exact same code than his one, but I still got problems.

My model is 'Klient' (here is my models.py) :

```
from django.db import models
import pandas as pd
from django.core.files import File
import datetime

class Klient(models.Model):
id_klient = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
nom_klient = models.CharField(max_length=42)
prenom_klient = models.CharField(max_length=42)
argent = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, 
                            verbose_name="Date ajout")
associations=models.TextField(null=True)
historique_transactions=models.FileField(default='/Users/antoinepradier/Desktop/site/site_kfet/site_K/historique/historique_transactions.xlsx')

def __str__(self):
    return(self.nom_klient+' '+self.prenom_klient)
```

Here is my html file (accueil.html) :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input id="n" type="text" name="n"/>
```

My accueil.js is as follows :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( "input#n" ).autocomplete({
                        source: "{% url "autoco" %}",
                        minLength: 2
    });
});
</script>
```

My view :

```
def autoco(request):
 term = request.GET.get('term')
 bslk = Klient.objects.filter(nom_klient__istartswith=term)
 res = []
 for b in bslk:
      dict = {'nom':b.nom_klient, 'prenom':b.prenom_klient}
      res.append(dict)
 return HttpResponse(json.dumps(res))
```

And finally my url :

```
url(r'^autoco/$', views.autoco, name='autoco'),
```

When I start typing the letters of a "Klient" nom_klient, nothing appears... Can someone help me to make it works?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to get the value of `term` but not passing it along.

Comment: Check in browsers console that the ajax request is made and has no errors in it.

Comment: The browser consol tells me this error :

`jquery-ui.min.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: a.curCSS is not a function
    at String.<anonymous> `

Comment: And what about the AJAX request and response

Comment: I'm new to AJAX so I don't know how to check that @RohanKumar

Comment: Open your URL, press F12, go to network tab then type  "nom_klient" in textbox and see that there is any URL called in Network tab and check the response.

Comment: when I type ' http://localhost:8000/site_K/autoco/?term=pr ' in my browser, I got this answer : [{"nom": "Pradier", "prenom": "Antoine"}]

Comment: I've done what you told me, I got a 404 Error (Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/favicon.ico)